What is the purpose of the hatch door in the floor?
In the movie Oddity, Darcy, Dani's sister, is killed by falling through the opened hatch door on the first floor, onto the ground floor.
This hatch door seems to be built in as an integral part of the house architecture. What could be the reasons for such a hatch door to be built into the first floor? This hatch door is big enough to almost completely block the whole footpath and someone would very likely fall if it is opened. A built-in disaster waiting to happen, I would say.
I attached a screenshot; this wooden path is on the 1st floor, a hatchdoor is in the middle of this wooden path (we cannot see this hatch door). It is a square shaped hatch door that takes almost the entire width of this path.


Is this an old house? Perhaps the hatch had a purpose in its earlier history, before becoming residential?

It made transporting heavy objects from one floor to another much easier. They were often accompanied by an overhead hook.

It used to be very common, I believe, especially in farmhouses. What makes this hatch door "an integral part of the architecture", by the way? Because the door is of the same old wood as the floor? Because the basement is built around it?

The purpose is to have a character fall down it.

And where is this hatch door, in what part of the house?

@Joachim, I attached a new screenshot.

I'm afraid Valorum's comment is the only true answer, in that case: this situation strikes me as architecturally (and practically) absurd for any other reason. It seems any type of load could be lowered or lifted on the other side of the balustrade. The only exception could be that the ladder to reach this balustrade can only be accessed through the hatch door.

Not an answer but: it is unclear if the trap door was made for the movie or if it is there for ease of lifting as mentioned above, but the film was shot in the stables of a place called Bantry House in West Cork Ireland. The filmmaker used this location in a previous movie with sets and he said he really liked the space and wanted to write a film around the place after they removed the sets. He is friends with the owners. https://www.rogerebert.com/interviews/damian-mccarthy-oddity-interview
